# How to use `{% cache %}` and `{% paginate %}` together?

Tags: cache, pagination

When using cache tag with pagination should the tag go outside the pagination tag?

```
{% cache %}
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
    {% paginate craft.entries.section('employment').endDate('>= ' ~ now).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
    {% for entry in pageEntries %}
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 cell">
            <div class="news-card" data-equalizer-watch>
                <div class="card-section text-center">
                    <h5><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h5>
                    <p>
                    <span class="label my-purple">
                        {% if entry.openUntilFilled %}
                            Open Until Filled
                        {% else %}
                            Job Closing: {{ entry.endDate.format('M j, Y') }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </span>
                    </p>
                    <p>{{ entry.body|length > 1 ? entry.body|striptags|slice(0, 150) ~ '...' : entry.body }}</p>
                    <p><a class="more" href="{{ entry.url }}">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="small-12 cell">
        {% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>&nbsp;{% endif %}
        {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the database query you'd want to cache is this:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('employment').endDate('>= ' ~ now).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

So to get the benefits of caching, it needs to be within the cache tag.

Comment: Just to be clear and avoid confusion - Craft does not cache the query; the cache tags only cache the output HTML.